# What is wrong with my Oracle 10gr2 check constraint? Trying to enforce a date range

Tags: database, oracle, constraints, date

I want to enforce CHECK constraint on a date range such that all dates in column BIRTH_DATE are less than tomorrow and greater than or equal to 100 years ago.  I tried this expression in a CHECK constraint:

```
BIRTH_DATE >= (sysdate - numtoyminterval(100, 'YEAR')) AND BIRTH_DATE < sysdate + 1
```

But I received the error "ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint"

Is there a way to accomplish this using a CHECK constraint instead of a trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A check constraint expression has to be deterministic, so this sort of sliding date range is not enforcable in a check constraint.  From the [SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF01111)

> Conditions of check constraints cannot
>   contain the following constructs:
>
> ```
> * Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions
> * Calls to the functions that are not deterministic (CURRENT_DATE,
> ```
>
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE, LOCALTIMESTAMP, SESSIONTIMEZONE,
>   SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, UID, USER, and
>   USERENV)

Answer (score 5):

As for why Oracle makes this restriction: check constraints must always evaluate to TRUE, even for updates.  If you added a 99 year-old to the database, and then tried to update the person's email address (e.g.) in 2 year's time you would receive a check constraint violation.

What you could do, if appropriate, is have another column CREATED_DATE that defaults to SYSDATE, and make the constraint:

```
BIRTH_DATE >= (CREATED_DATE - numtoyminterval(100, 'YEAR')) 
AND BIRTH_DATE < CREATED_DATE + 1
```

However, if you really only want to perform the check at INSERT time then do it in a database trigger or in the API code.

Comment: Prefer the in database API solution over the trigger solution.  Triggers should only be used when absolutely necessary.